# Switch between am/pm on NSDate

Tags: nsdate

Hi I made a button that let's you add a calendar event, but I would like to get the date on a 12 hour clock and switch between am and pm with a button.

Here is the code for the calendar event:

```
- (IBAction)agregaevento:(id)sender {
NSString *d1 = dia.text;
NSString *m1 = mes.text;
NSString *a1 = anio.text;
NSString *h1 = hora.text;
NSString *m2 = minutos.text;
NSString *fechadelevento = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@ %@:%@", d1, m1, a1,h1,m2];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Montevideo"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
[Dateevento addObject:fechadelevento];
NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:fechadelevento];
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
                myEvent.title = ddText.text;
                myEvent.startDate = myDate;
                myEvent.endDate = myDate;
                [myEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                NSError *err;
                [store saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this dates d1,m1, etc? If you want am/pm information you should get it from the source and append it to fechadelevento. Then, assuming that you checked your date format and incoming date to be in same format, you should set current date format as @"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"

Comment: I get the date from some textfields, try to set the format as @"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a" doesn't work.

Comment: before setting that format, you should also append the am/pm information to fechadelevento.